# Sm Shopby Cannot Initialize Reindexer Process

Tags: php, magento, pdo

I seem to be having an issues indexing on Magento. All available indexes index fine except for one:

Sm Shopby

When indexing through the following error, but I can't quite see what the issue is.

````
Sm Shopby index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '`main_table`.`frontend_input`' in 'where clause'' in /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(740): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(572): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(741): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/local/Sm/Shopby/Model/Resource/Indexer/Attribute.php(29): Varien_Data_Collection->getIterator()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/local/Sm/Shopby/Model/Resource/Indexer/Attribute.php(20): Sm_Shopby_Model_Resource_Indexer_Attribute->reindexSeoUrlKeys()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Sm_Shopby_Model_Resource_Indexer_Attribute->reindexAll()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#17 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#18 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '`main_table`.`frontend_input`' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, `additional_table`.* FROM `eav_attribute` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` AS `additional_table` ON additional_table.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id WHERE (`main_table`.`entity_type_id` = '4') AND (```main_table```.```frontend_input``` IN('select', 'multiselect'))' in /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(740): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(572): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(741): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/local/Sm/Shopby/Model/Resource/Indexer/Attribute.php(29): Varien_Data_Collection->getIterator()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/local/Sm/Shopby/Model/Resource/Indexer/Attribute.php(20): Sm_Shopby_Model_Resource_Indexer_Attribute->reindexSeoUrlKeys()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Sm_Shopby_Model_Resource_Indexer_Attribute->reindexAll()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/domain/sub-domain/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#17 {main}
````

I've looked in the Pdo.php file but I'm not 100% sure what I'm after. I tried a couple of queries which managed to fix Product Flat Data & Category Flat Data, but not this specific index.

Any clues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

n into this exact issue as well. I narrowed it down to a problem with Attribute.php.
Open app/code/local/Sm/Shopby/Model/Resource/Indexer/Attribute.php

Around line 65 you will find the protected function called _getAttribute.
Change from this,

```
 protected function _getAttributes($attributeId = null){
        $collection = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
            ->getEntityType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)
            ->getAttributeCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('`main_table`.`frontend_input`', array('in' => array('select', 'multiselect')));
        if (!empty($attributeId)) {
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('`main_table`.`attribute_id`', $attributeId);
        }

        return $collection;
    }
```

to this code instead,

```
 protected function _getAttributes($attributeId = null){
        $collection = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
            ->getEntityType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)
            ->getAttributeCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.frontend_input', array('in' => array('select', 'multiselect')));
        if (!empty($attributeId)) {
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('main_table.attribute_id', $attributeId);
        }

        return $collection;
    }
```

What changed?
The only thing I changed was removing the apostrophes (´) at lines 69 and 71. Which means that ´main_table´.´frontend_input' is now changed into main_table.frontend_input. Now the scripts updates SQL properly. Both in Admin and Shell.

Answer (score 7):

Same problem and solved now.

The column `'main_table.frontend_input'` exists but `` '`main_table`.`frontend_input`' `` (in SQL query transforms to ```` ```main_table```.```frontend_input``` ````) not.

Just go to Sm_Shopby_Model_Resource_Indexer_Attribute and remove `` ` ``

Update:
Sm_Shopby_Model_Resource_Indexer_Attribute is a class of SM Shopby extension.

The file stay in magento_folder/app/code/ ... /Sm/Shopby/Model/Resource/Indexer/Attribute.php and the function to change is _getAttributes.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. Looking in the DB, the table: Sm_Shopby_Model_Resource_Indexer_Attribute doesn't exist. I've also tried removing the backticks in the 'Attribute.php' file that calls 'addFieldToFilter'. Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for not specify, this ( Sm_Shopby_Model_Resource_Indexer_Attribute ) isn't a table but a class of the extension.


magento_folder/app/code/ ... /Sm/Shopby/Model/Resource/Indexer/Attribute.php -> function _getAttributes